# Onclick on button is not working in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs (Nextjs),I put my "css,images,js" files in "public" folder,But my
Menu bar is not showing (onclick is not working),How can i make this working so after click on this button menu will display,Here is my code

```
<button className="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">
        <img src="images/menu_btn.png" />
</button>
```

Comment: call the function in in curly bracket not in the parenthesis like this -onClick={your_function}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending a string to onClick function, so change your onClick button to this,

```
onClick={ openNav }
```

Answer (score 1):

As others are mentioning, you need your `onClick` attribute to call a handler function, ie.

```js
const openNav = () => {
   console.log("openNav has been clicked");
}

<button className="openbtn" onClick={openNav}>
        <img src="images/menu_btn.png" />
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you're passing openNav as a string, rather than a function - you can't invoke a string literal.

Secondly, you're trying to instantly invoke the openNav function in the onclick handler, which means openNav will fire as the code is run in the browser.

You'll want to do either:

```
onClick={openNav}
```

or if you want to pass an argument

```
onClick={(arg) => openNav(arg)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call your `openNav` function that way (else your are just sending a string) and use `onClick` (instead of `onclick`):

```
<button className="openbtn" onClick={openNav}>
    <img src="images/menu_btn.png" />
</button>
```

Comment: Maybe emphasise too that it's `onClick` not `onclick` in React.

Comment: @Nico_ i am getting following error 

"ReferenceError: openNav is not defined "

Comment: Have you written an `openNav` function @Rick?